# Command does not run at startup but run manually

Tags: scripts, startup, startup-applications

I have this command that remove the capslock delay.

```
xkbcomp -xkb "$DISPLAY" - | sed 's#key <CAPS>.*#key <CAPS> {\
repeat=no,\
type[group1]="ALPHABETIC",\
symbols[group1]=[ Caps_Lock, Caps_Lock],\
actions[group1]=[ LockMods(modifiers=Lock),\
Private(type=3,data[0]=1,data[1]=3,data[2]=3)]\
};\
#' | xkbcomp -w 0 - "$DISPLAY"
```

It is in a bash script that run on startup, I know the script is running because it has more commands running and they work fine, this is the only one that is in the script and does not work, but if I run the script manually or I write the command in the terminal, it works. Any idea why this command does not work on startup?

Im using the "Startup Applications" to run the script.

Comment: Have you directed the output of the script to a file to see if there are any errors? How are you running the script at startup? cron, systemd? Which user is running the script. If root then the running environment may be wrong

Comment: Does your script have a proper shebang?

Comment: I will try to see the output, Im using the built-in "Startup Applications" to run the script, It is running as sudo. Yes, it does have proper shebang

Comment: It should not be running as sudo. You could try delaying the command a little using "sleep"

Comment: I couldnt try it yet. Yes, it is executable... as I said the other commands in the script are working fine.